# No encuentro el archivo que acabo de descargar

Tags: java, android

Tengo un código con el cual descargo un fichero en la carpeta descargas de Android, en el emulador aparece el pdf en dicha carpeta. Pero cuando ejecuto el siguiente código no funciona.

```
            downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri =Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxxx");
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);


            String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            String sdCard2 = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();

            downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri =Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxx");
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            File ficheroPrueba = new File(sdCard + "/pau_alem18je_compressed.pdf");
            if(ficheroPrueba.exists()){
                Log.v(TAG, "Hola");
            }
```

Permisos (android manifest):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

He probado con sdCard y sdCard2 como path pero sin conseguirlo

Comment: Revisaste el LogCat si muestra algún error? Que permisos tienes definidos y como los requieres?

Comment: El logcat no muestra ningún error, dejo los permisos en el mensaje inicial @Jorgesys He probado con otros path y si funciona bien el if, puede ser el path de la carpeta downloads el error?

Comment: Ok @Gorpe solo recuerda que el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE debe ser requerido manualmente para dispositivos con OS 6.0 o posterior, y usa setDestinationInExternalPublicDir() para definir el directorio donde se guardará el archivo, saludos.

Comment: Te aconsejo buscar el libro Absolute Java, fifth edition by Walter Savitch. Es un libro magnifico que te enseñara casi todo sobre manipulacion de ficheros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El directorio donde se descargará el archivo usando [`DownloadManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request) debe ser definido mediante el método [setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))**,

> [setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) Establece el destino local
>   del archivo descargado en una ruta dentro del directorio público de
>   almacenamiento externo

```
  request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, sdCard);
```

Ejemplo de acuerdo a el archivo que deseas descargar en tu pregunta:

```
    String fileToDownload = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19x7CJWU6Jc3fVPOJc7SN6b_a3qgXuQUz";
    String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri =Uri.parse(fileToDownload);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setTitle("Descargando archivo.");
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, sdCard);

    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Aprovecho para hacer una pregunta más, si quisiera descargar el pdf en otro directorio que no sea la carpeta de descargas como se haría? Por ejemplo una carpeta dentro de mi app @Jorgesys